# google analytics for single page api

Tags: google-analytics, singlepage

how to get the page views for a single page `eg:www.domain.com/product/?code=21` is there any api reference for this?

My idea is very similar to goo.gl/examplestring.info (to get the url stats)

Comment: I think im the google analytics tool you and specify params. Maybe this is what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to play around with what you can/cannot get from the api.

Then just run a query that looks something like this:

[image]

You can use RegEx too, to get at your page using the =~ operator. More info on operators [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary).